# Где в БД хранит SharePoint данные по пользователям?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint

https://**siteurl**/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx

Интересует, откуда SharePoint берет данные на этой странице, нашел таблицу **UserInfo** в БД контента сайта, но там нет данных по Департаменту, Должности и др.

Не буду объяснять почему это нужно. Помогите найти, в какой таблице хранятся эти данные. Спасибо.

Comment: разве такая информация берется не из Active Directory?

Comment: Предполагаю,что берется из АД и хранится в таблицах БД SharePoint'а, как например номер сотового телефона, поле tp_Mobile в вышеупомянутой табличке

Comment: у меня есть проект который работает на sharepoint foundation. и вот данные такие как должность, номер тел и тд. хранятся в таблице dbo.AllUserData

Comment: Спасибо, но, не нашел таких данных в такой же таблице SharePoint Server 2013

Comment: Вам необходимо вытащить эти данные или произвести с ними некие манипуляции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft не рекоммендует производить какие либо манипуляции с подобными данными, однако SELECT можно будет запросить:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
[Login] = upf.NTName,
Name = upf.PreferredName,
Email = upf.Email,
Modified = upf.LastUserUpdate,
Property = pl.PropertyName,
Value = upv.PropertyVal

FROM
UserProfile_Full upf,
UserProfileValue upv,
PropertyList pl

WHERE
upv.RecordID = upf.RecordID
AND pl.PropertyID = upv.PropertyID
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24f97e07-6b90-4e98-b16d-ae0b4f3621af/where-is-sharepoint-2010-my-site-profile-details-stored-in-the-sql-db?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Всё верно, часть информации может храниться в **User Profile Service**, для этой службы в SharePoint предусмотрена отдельная БД. Можно еще использовать PowerShell для получения всех полей:  http://ulmaskulov.blogspot.ru/2016/05/sharepoint-upsa-powershell.html

Comment: спасибо за ответ и за код, прям каждая строчка прокоменчена

Answer (score 0):

Для этого microsoft рекомендует [stsadmin](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2007-status-of-64d1a33e).  [enumusers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc263220(v=office.12).aspx)

```
stsadm.exe -o enumusers -url <URL-имя>
```

Если нужно на c# накопал такой пример работы с юзверями

```
                using (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite site = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(

                    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.  SPControl.GetContextSite(HttpContext.Current).ID))
                {
                    using (Microsoft.SharePoint.  SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))
                    {
                        Boolean allowUnsafeUpdate = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
                        try
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                            // Get user identity name
                            String login = owner;
                            String loginName = login;
                            String name = owner;
                            String email = "";
                            String notes = "Automatically added user";

                            // Or take from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[...];
                            String groupName = "Viewers";
                            web.SiteUsers.Add(loginName, email, name, notes);
                            web.Groups[groupName].AddUser(loginName, email, name, notes);


                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString());
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdate;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```